# Stop Firebug lite from automatically opening the console on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, firebug, firebug-lite

I used the code below to stop Firebug lite from automatically opening on pageload on Chrome on  an Android device.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${cooingbStatic}/js/firebug-lite/build/firebug-lite.js#debug=false">
```

I also tried this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${cooingbStatic}/js/firebug-lite/build/firebug-lite.js#debug=false,startOpened=false">
```

But neither seem to work.

One more thing I tried...but that didn't work is this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${cooingbStatic}/js/firebug-lite/build/firebug-lite.js">
        {
           debug: false,
           startOpened: false
        }
</script>
```

I'm using Firebug lite 1.4.

How do I stop Firebug opening the console automatically on page load ?